# Accessing the attribute of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have code in PHP and javascript, my php variable transformed it into javascript variable:

```
var countries_list = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($countries_list);?>');
```

When I do a console.log me returns the array:
[image]

**How I can access the attribute *price*?**

EDIT: **I want the key values (deu, esp, gbr, etc) too**

[image]

Comment: `object.aut.price` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countries_list` is not an array but an object literal.

To access price for each country you can do

```
for (var countryCode in countries_list) {
    var country = countries_list[countryCode];
    console.log(countryCode, country, country.price);
}
```

Comment: but I want to also get the key value (aut,bel,irl,ita), This code does not work, return Object: `for (var key in countries_list) {
        var countries = countries_list[key];
        console.log(countries);
   }`

Comment: `countryCode` is the key value, just log it and see it for yourself